# Correct value for appname in AWS Cognito based authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I am trouble-shooting a customization of the AWS-supplied CognitoSyncDemo for my own app. I built the authentication backend for my iOS Mobile Hub app using the Cloud Formation instructions.

I am getting an error response when I try to login a user:

```
Error matching signature
```

The signature hash is calculated from values I provide, including a value called `appname` which is defined in the demo like this

```
// This is the default value, if you modified your backend configuration
// update this value as appropriate
NSString *const DeveloperAuthAppName = @"awscognitodeveloperauthenticationsample";
```

I am not sure whether I should change this value or not. None of the various forms of the name of my app that I see in the AWS Console has stopped the error. Where do I find the correct value for DeveloperAuthAppName?

Comment: Did you get any solution for same?